# Node.js & express.js: generate .sh file

Tags: node.js, express, sh

In node.js and express.js is it possible to generate a file output with a .sh extension?

Right now I have the file outputting, but without an extension:

```
ret = bash info goes here
res.header('Content-Type', 'text/x-sh');
res.end(ret);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
ret = bash info goes here    
res.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "myfile.sh");
res.end(ret);
```

Comment: Right - you might also look into the express helpers [res.download()](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.download%28%29), [res.attachment()](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.attachment%28%29), and [res.sendfile()](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.sendfile%28%29).